# Получение ответа от сервера с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть модальное окно регистрации с полями и кнопкой `зарегистрироваться`. При нажатии на кнопку берутся значения из всех полей и отправляется ajax запрос на сервер, где происходит валидация. Если пользователь ввел неправильные данные то в блоке `showRegError` отображается список что пользователь ввел неправильно, а снизу должна остаться форма. Если пользователь ввел правильные данные то в блоке `showSuccess` должно отображаться сообщение об успешной регистрации но уже без формы. Код формы:

```
 <div class="showRegError">
 </div>
               <div class="showSuccess"> 
                  <form class="form-horizontal regForm"> ... </form>
               </div>
```

На данный момент получается выводить список ошибок в блоке `showRegError`. Т.е. с помощью ajax запроса получаю ответ в виде html, но как мне определить что пришло, ошибка или успешная регистрация? :

```
success: function(html){
                         $('.showRegError').html(html).show();
                       }
```

Если есть ошибки, то просто вывести их в цикле(должно выводится в `showRegError`):

```
 for ($i = 0; $i<count($err); $i++)
    {
        echo $err[$i] . '<br>';
    }
```

Если нет ошибок, то (в блок `showSuccess`):

```
echo '<p>Регистрация прошла успешно!</p>';
```

Comment: Была идея(скорее всего, кривая) если при валидации есть ошибка, то сохранить ее в сессию `$_SESSION['err']` и уже в js как-то смотреть эту сессию пустая она или нет

Comment: Добавьте пример данных, которые возвращает сервер при успешном и ошибочном сценариях

Comment: @AGS17, добавил, если я вас правильно понял

Comment: видимо неправильно вы меня поняли. Вы пишите `success: function(html){` - так вот что содержит в себе этот `html`? То же самое интересует и для `error: function(html){`.

Comment: @AGS17,  Вывел `html` с помощью `console.log` : `Имя должно быть не меньше 3 симоволов<br>Введите телефон<br>`.  А `error: function(html){` у меня вообще нету

Comment: @AGS17, а при успешной валидации `html` должен содержать: `<p>Регистрация прошла успешно!</p>`

Comment: Это не корректно. У вас успешный и ошибочный сценарии возвращают 200 код. Сделайте, чтобы ошибочный сценарий кидал 400 BadRequst. (Я не php, но думаю это можно сделать [с помощью этой функции](http://php.net/http-response-code)).

Comment: @AGS17, Спасибо! Буду разбираться. Я правильно понимаю, что если есть ошибки нужно как-то получить `error: function(html){`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки складываешь например в массив (если их нет, массив пустой):

```
$errorMessage['Ошибка 1', 'Ошибка 2']
```

Сообщение об успехе кладешь в массив (если их нет, массив пустой)

```
$successMessage['Все хорошо 1', 'Все хорошо 2']
```

Складываешь их в итоговый массив:

```
$returnJson['errors'] = $errorMessage;
$returnJson['success'] = $successMessage;
```

Преобразуешь в json и возвращаешь в Ajax

```
echo json_encode($returnJson, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

В js:

```
$('#add').on('click', function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',

        success: function (html) {
            html = JSON.parse(html);
            if(html.errors)
            {
                $('.showRegError').html('');
                i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < html.errors.length; i++) {
                    $('.showRegError').append('<li>' + html.errors[i] + '</li>');
                }
            }
            else if(html.success)
            {
                $('.showSuccess').html('html.success');
            }
        },
    })
});
```

Comment: Сделал как у вас сделано. `html` в `console.log` показывает: `{"errors":["Имя должно быть не меньше 3 симоволов","Введите телефон"],"success":null}` . Но на странице ничего не меняется

Comment: У меня в коде jQuery была опечатка, вместо errors, было error. Я поправил в трех местах. Попробуйте тоже исправить.

Comment: Все равно не работает(

Comment: А если я попытаюсь вывести `console.log(html.errors);` должен работать? А то у меня сейчас `undefined`

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что console.log(html) возвращает сроку, а console.log(html.errors) выдает undefined ?

Comment: Да именно так все происходит

Comment: У Вас точно стоит в коде вызова ajax, такая строка: datatype: 'json' ?

Comment: Вот сам запрос: `$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: urlSend,
                        datatype: 'json',
                        data: dataSend,
                        success: function(html){`

Comment: Немного изменил код. Сделал так чтобы возвращался только один массив, если нет ошибок, то он пустой и валидация прошла успешно. Теперь проблема в выводе ошибок. Пытаюсь сделать так:  `for (i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
                                         $('.showRegError').append('<li>' + html[i] + '</li>');
                                                console.log(html[i]);
                                       }`

Comment: При этом цикл проходится не по элементам, массива а по каждой букве. Как будто он не воспринимает `html` как массив

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разобрался. Из строки получил массив с помощью `JSON.parse`  и теперь все работает

Comment: Странно, у меня работает без этого. Но в любом случае добавлю эту строку в итоговый ответ, на тут случай если кто-то еще будет смотреть.